# Loop PHP, NO DUPLICATE Field from by group, sum mysql

Tags: php, mysql, loops

this is my table 'dp'

```
Year      | Month     | Payment|  Payer_ID | Payment_Recipient |
2008/2009 | July      | 100000 |     1     |        John       |
2008/2009 | August    | 200000 |     1     |        Jane       |
2009/2010 | August    | 150000 |     1     |        Jane       |
2009/2010 | September | 175000 |     1     |        John       |
```

**I need output like this in my php page :**

```
Year      |       July     |      August   |     September | 
2008/2009 | 100000 | John  | 200000 | Jane |    0   |   -  | 
2009/2010 |    0   |   -   | 150000 | Jane | 175000 | John |
```

I use this sql query :

```
$query_sql = "SELECT
   year
 , SUM(IF(Month='July', Payment, 0)) As 'July'
 , SUM(IF(Month='August', Payment, 0)) As 'August'
 , SUM(IF(Month='September', Payment, 0)) As 'September'
FROM 
 dp
WHERE 
 Payer_ID = 1
GROUP BY
 Year";


<table>
<tr>
<td>year</td>
<td>July</td>
<td>August</td>
<td>September</td>
</tr>
<?php
while($data=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $data['year']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $data['July']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $data['August']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $data['September']; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>
```

and the output always like this :

```
Year      |  July  | August | September | 
2009/2010 |    0   | 150000 | 175000    |
```

only show 1 year (not looping).

Can somebody help me to fix my code in 'sum(if' to include payment recipient and fix my variable in php to loop?

Comment: You must get rid of the SUM because you don't want the results to be aggregated for all the users. Just rewrite the SQL without grouping. Then you'll have the data in PHP and you can start working from there.

Comment: @gontrollez no, I can't do that because when I do that the column year will be duplicate, and I dont want that.

Comment: If there is more than one Payment Recipient per month you'll have to do the way I suggested and treat the aggregation in your code.

Comment: @gontrollez the main point is the year must not be duplicate and loop for every year, and the month is in correct position by each year.
that's why I need code fix for making variable from that sql select command, so I can use it to show in my php.

Comment: Hi there. Just so you know, there's no need to edit posts to mark as "solved" as per normal forums. Awarding the tick is the way to go here! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Crude SQL way of doing it:-

```
   SELECT DISTINCT dp.Year, SubJuly.Payment, SubJuly.Payment_Recipient, SubAugust.Payment, SubAugust.Payment_Recipient, SubSeptember.Payment, SubSeptember.Payment_Recipient
    FROM dp
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    ( 
        SELECT Year, Month, Payment, Payer_ID, Payment_Recipient 
        FROM dp
        WHERE Month = 'July'
    ) SubJuly
    ON dp.Year = SubJuly.Year
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    ( 
        SELECT Year, Month, Payment, Payer_ID, Payment_Recipient 
        FROM dp
        WHERE Month = 'August'
    ) SubAugust
    ON dp.Year = SubAugust.Year
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    ( 
        SELECT Year, Month, Payment, Payer_ID, Payment_Recipient 
        FROM dp
        WHERE Month = 'September'
    ) SubSeptember
    ON dp.Year = SubSeptember.Year
WHERE  dp.Payer_ID = 1
```

It could probably done more efficiently by using a list of months / years and LEFT JOINing that against the original table, then just working on the change of row in the php.

Lobbing that back into your original php:-

```
<?php


$query_sql = "   SELECT DISTINCT dp.Year, SubJuly.Payment, SubJuly.Payment_Recipient, SubAugust.Payment, SubAugust.Payment_Recipient, SubSeptember.Payment, SubSeptember.Payment_Recipient
    FROM dp
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    ( 
        SELECT Year, Month, Payment, Payer_ID, Payment_Recipient 
        FROM dp
        WHERE Month = 'July'
    ) SubJuly
    ON dp.Year = SubJuly.Year
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    ( 
        SELECT Year, Month, Payment, Payer_ID, Payment_Recipient 
        FROM dp
        WHERE Month = 'August'
    ) SubAugust
    ON dp.Year = SubAugust.Year
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    ( 
        SELECT Year, Month, Payment, Payer_ID, Payment_Recipient 
        FROM dp
        WHERE Month = 'September'
    ) SubSeptember
    ON dp.Year = SubSeptember.Year
WHERE  dp.Payer_ID = 1";

....................
?>
<table>
<tr>
<td>year</td>
<td colspan='2'>July</td>
<td colspan='2'>August</td>
<td colspan='2'>September</td>
</tr>
<?php
while($data=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
{
    echo "<tr><td>".implode("</td><td>", $data)."</td></tr>";
} 
?>
</table>
```

Note you probably should be using mysqli_* functions rather than the mysql_* functions.

Comment: I can't use list of years, because every payer_id has different payment. anyway how should i use that select you give to my php loop so it can result loop every year with each month in correct year.like the output i need above.

Comment: That SQL should give you a row for each output line

Comment: Yes, awesome, but i mean how should i convert each data to variable in php like I used to do with mysql_fetch_array and the table is loop for every years (but no duplicate)?
i need it to make it variable (like my first script <td><?php echo $data['July']; ?></td>).

Comment: YES, THAT'S WHAT I WANT!!, Thank you so much, it works like a charm. Awesome.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct.. i think you use

```
 mysql_fetch_array
```

function before while loop also. check your code

Comment: no, it's not working, the loop is not working, just work for the first row. anyway thanks